# Add identity column to existing table in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, primary-key, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table "MY_TABLE" in Snowflake that I would like to add an identity column to. I tried

```
ALTER TABLE "MY_TABLE" 
    ADD COLUMN primary_key int IDENTITY(1,1);
```

But this returns

```
SQL compilation error: Cannot add column 'PRIMARY_KEY' with non-constant default to non-empty table 'MY_TABLE'.
```

Is this just not possible in snowflake?

To try to get around this limitation, I tried to create a temp version of the table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "MY_TABLE_TEMP" LIKE "MY_TABLE"
ALTER TABLE "MY_TABLE_TEMP" ADD COLUMN primary_key int IDENTITY(1,1)

INSERT INTO "MY_TABLE_TEMP"
    SELECT * FROM "MY_TABLE";
```

But now I get the error

```
SQL compilation error: Insert value list does not match column list expecting <x+1> but got <x>
```

Which sort of makes sense, since I am not passing the primary key. At this point it seems like I may have to manually enter the list of x (which is a very high number) of column names into the sql query, so I am wondering if I am just doing this all wrong. Has anyone else run into a similar issue?

Comment: Snowflake doesn't seem to like a new auto increment column being added to an existing table.  Given that your table seems to be empty, you could just modify your create statement.

Answer (score 10):

Can you try this

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE_TEMP LIKE TEST_TABLE;
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE_TEMP ADD COLUMN primary_key int IDENTITY(1,1);

create or replace sequence seq_01 start = 1 increment = 1;

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE_TEMP 
SELECT *,seq_01.NEXTVAL FROM TEST_TABLE;

SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE_TEMP;
```

Comment: Not OP, but I have the same issue and the ALTER TABLE statement is failing with OP's original message.

Comment: Actually there is a reason why snowflake should never enable the ALTER TABLE solution to populate the IDENTITY column for a non-empty table. The answer is in the architecture of SNOWFLAKE. Think how many micro partitions will need to be touched and what it will mean to the compute cost?

Comment: Upon further exploration, I think there is an issue. This seems to use a different sequence for the identity column and to seed the initial values of that column. The next line that gets inserted to the table will start again at 1. I might be able to work around this by doing IDENTITY(r,1) where r is the number of rows in the table though.

Comment: Good one, 2023 and still works just fine!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `IDENTITY`, you could use your own `SEQUENCE` to create a unique id for each row.

Fixing the example in the question with a sequence:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE seq1;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "MY_TABLE_TEMP" LIKE "MY_TABLE";

ALTER TABLE "MY_TABLE_TEMP" 
ADD COLUMN primary_key int DEFAULT seq1.nextval;


INSERT INTO "MY_TABLE_TEMP"
SELECT *, seq1.nextval 
FROM "MY_TABLE";
```

(after posting this answer, I noticed it's very similar to Rajib's)

Comment: Not OP, but I'm in somewhat the same situation (using a sequence instead of identity EDIT: And also with identity), and I'm getting OP's same error when trying to execute the ALTER TABLE you wrote up there.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to create sequence. You can just specify columns in the insert:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE_TEMP LIKE TEST_TABLE;
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE_TEMP ADD COLUMN primary_key int IDENTITY(1,1);

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE_TEMP (col1,col2,...) 
SELECT col1,col2,... FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

If you want to add your primary column in other place than last you need to create DDL for your table. Than edit it: add your primary column and change the table name. The insert will work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new table with the identity column.  Copy the data over.  Delete the original table.  Rename the new one.

Answer (score -1):

Just a hunch, but have you tried including the target_col_name in the insert statement.  I'm assuming that if you don't specify them, it is expecting the additional column you just added in the select statement.