# Add only unique rows in SnowFlake Cloud Database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to automate the ingestion of data from a source into a SnowFlake Cloud Database. There is no way to extract only unique rows from the source. So the entire data will be extracted during every ingestion run. However, while adding to SnowFlake I only want to add the unique rows. How can this be achieved most optimally?

Further Information: Source is a DataStax Cassandra Graph.

Comment: Can you provide some more information?  
For instance is there a unique identifier or primary key in the data?  
Is this being loaded into a stage or in its final location?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63892582/add-identity-column-to-existing-table-in-snowflake

Comment: Are there duplicates in the data being extracted, duplicates between the extract and the target table, or both?

Comment: @DanielZagales Yes, there is a unique identifier. Data is being loaded in its final location. Essentially using the WebUI to upload a CSV.

Comment: @NickW No, there are no duplicates.

Comment: Apologies if my question was not clear but there have to be duplicates somewhere as that is the whole point of your question! Are you saying that there are no duplicates within your source and there are also no duplicates within your target but the same records do exist in both your source and target? If this is the case, how do you want to handle the duplicates: only insert new records into your target or insert new records and update existing records?

Comment: @NickW okay, I get your question. No, the issue is, once I have added say 100 rows. During the next round of ingestion, I will have 150 rows (100 earlier rows and 50 new rows), I want to add only the new 50 rows and not the earlier 100 rows that are already there.

Comment: OK - then just follow Mike's MERGE answer below with just a "when not matched then insert" statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a key that you can use to determine which records need to be loaded, the idea scenario would be to load the data to a stage table in Snowflake and then run a MERGE statement using the new data and apply to your target table.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

If there is no key, you might want to consider running an INSERT OVERWRITE statement and just replacing the table with the new incoming data.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#insert-using-overwrite

Answer (score 1):

You will have to stage it to a table in snowflake for ingestion and then move it to the destination table using select distinct.