# Autoincrement column in Snowflake using DBT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

We have a system that uses GUID / UUID as primary keys that we are ingesting into snowflake using DBT. However we have downstream systems that can only handle Primary Keys of 10 digits. Is there a way we can map the GUID/UUID to a 10-digit number and in put in a reference that table so that we can use that 10-digit number in the downstream apps rather than the GUID/UUID?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of UUID you're using, the first and middle bits may not be random, but the last bits always will be. UUIDs are hex numbers, so you can take the last segment (12 hex digits), convert to binary, then convert to a base 10 integer, and truncate the result so it's only 10 digits long. This would provide you with mapping from a UUID that you wouldn't have to store anywhere, and that would be deterministic (assuming a record's uuid never changes). ***However***, 10 digits isn't that much entropy (only 10 billion unique values), and you would expect a collision after only about 100,000 records. So this probably isn't the right approach to your problem.

Snowflake offers a bunch of solutions for creating integer sequences, but not all play nicely with dbt (e.g., [`create sequence`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-sequence.html) is a truly automatic auto-incrementing ID, but it won't work if you're constantly dropping and re-creating tables, as dbt does with models).

Assuming there are no hard-deletes upstream from the model, I would probably `order by created_at` (maybe by `created_at, uuid` to break ties) and then use `row_number()` to build an integer ID for each record. This isn't great performance-wise, but it's very simple conceptually, and your data is probably already mostly sorted by `created_at` anyway.

Comment: Hi. I had thought about this. But we really don't have natural way to sequence the GUID/UUID from the source. There is no created_at field.

Comment: Can you alter the source table to add an auto-incrementing column using a new Sequence? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63893146/10813082